# How to remove "=>" from json output in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am stuck with what I think is a simple problem. I am creating json and need to have the format be:

```
[{ "source" : "google / organic", "visits" : 20 }]
```

And here is what I get:

```
[{"source"=>"google / organic", "visits"=>20}]
```

Here is the model (campaign_results.rb)

```
  def as_json(options = {})
      {   "source" => source,
          "visits" => visits, 
      }
  end
```

In the controller:

```
def show
    @campaign_summary = CampaignResults.all
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= raw @campaign_summary.as_json %>
```

Any suggestions on what I should do to replace the "=>" with ":"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `#to_json`:

```
<%= raw @campaign_summary.as_json.to_json %>
```